# List index out of range when reading a file

Tags: list, file, indexing

I am opening a file and trying to read the 3rd value on each line. Here is my code

```
myfile = 'dummy2.pepmasses'
fileObj = open(myfile, 'r')


line = fileObj.readline()
while line:
    line = fileObj.readline()
    linesplit = line.split()
    weight = linesplit[2]
    print(weight)
fileObj.close
```

This is resulting the third value being correctly displayed however there is an index error at the bottom but I'm not sure why as I'm not specifying a range of values to read, but rather just to read everything. I believe the issue is that when I read the file there is a blank [] at the bottom, although there are no blank lines on the actual file so I don't understand what is happening.

Any ideas appreciated, thanks.

The end of my file is

```
STE50,YCL032W            36    1262.6920  0 0 QQGLHPAIMLR
STE50,YCL032W            37     174.1117  0 0 R
STE50,YCL032W            38     174.1117  0 0 R
STE50,YCL032W            39    2081.8783  0 0 GDFEEVAMMNGSDNVTPGGR
STE50,YCL032W            40     131.0947  0 0 L*
```

The error generated is

```
174.1117
2081.8783
131.0947
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Test/Test.py", line 12, in <module>
weight = linesplit[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please add your example file, or rather the end of it, since there probably **is** an empty line there, or anywhere else in the file.

Comment: Before `weight = linesplit[2]`, test if exist `if linesplit[2]`

Comment: @gonutz This is the end of my file as read on notepad++
`THR4,YCR053W             59     277.1461  0 0 MK
THR4,YCR053W             60     131.0947  0 0 L*
YCL038C                   1    1993.8509  0 0 MSYGTINDMNESVTNYR
YCL038C                   2     259.1897  0 0 IK
YCL038C                   3     146.1056  0 0 LOPKPPI`

Comment: Also, what language is this and what OS are you on?

Comment: @gonutz Python 3, and I'm using Windows. Also I edited my first comment, thanks.

Comment: I assume you mean to say `line.split` and not `linesplit` since there is no such function.

Comment: @gonutz Oh that's just what I called it, probably a bad name I know but there is a `line.split`

Comment: It's okay I got it, I completely changed it to `text = r"dummy2.pepmasses"

oFile = open(text, 'r')
line = oFile.readline()[:-1]
while line:
    splitLine = line.split()
    print(splitLine[2])
    line = oFile.readline()[:-1]
    
oFile.close()`

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether `linesplit` has at least 3 values in it and only print the weight in that case.

Comment: All the lines have a least 3 values, except for when I print the list there is a [] at the bottom but it's not in the file so I don't know where it's coming from. I have tried to make a new file but it is still appearing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the " line.split() " command that's causing this blank element to appear but I'm not sure why